# How do I take large numbers of input around 100000 digits in length

Tags: c++

I want to take large input in c++ of variable k whose value is between 2 and $10^{100000}$ .

I could not get how to do that.

I tried long long but it doesn't work.

Source: https://www.codechef.com/JULY19B/problems/MMAX

Comment: Yes, long long for sure won&#39;t work. Maybe try this https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/22566 
In the post actual link to git: https://gist.github.com/ar-pa/957297fb3f88996ead11

Comment: 100000 digits is a lot of digits. Way more than any stock integer type. How precise must this input be?

Comment: Thinking on this a wee bit more, what sort of mathematical operations do you need to perform on this number? If the answer is none, you have a great case for using a `string`.

Comment: @user4581301 I have added the source in question.

Comment: @zviad I have added the source in question.

Comment: Start with something simpler like K values of a size you can manage. This may give you ideas on how you can perform the task with larger numbers.

Comment: You should use a multi-precision integer library. There are plenty around [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) for instance

Comment: Try this: https://gist.github.com/ar-pa/957297fb3f88996ead11

Answer (score 1):

'unsigned long long' is the largest one, about 10^19.
also there are 10^82 atoms in the observable universe.

Comment: I have added the source in question.

Comment: @cattt i don't know what you're doing but you cannot assign a greater value to a var in cpp if the problem requires it anyway you will need to find an alternate mathematics path for the computation.

Comment: This is a algorithms question. There will be a trick that allows you to avoid the number entirely or transform it in such a way that the size does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to read the number as a string, not as some number data type.
I've used this snippet for reading the large number, based on an answer to a similar question on Quora:

```
string s; 
int b, c;

c = s.size();
int arr[c];
b = 0;
while(b != c)
{
    arr[b] = s[b] - '0';
    b++;
}
```

And afterwards, you do your stuff with the resulting array instead of the input number.